# Ubuntu 11.10 PHP don't proceed

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-11.10

i've just setup a LAMP development environment on my laptop, all works fine except for php. Apache don't process PHP code embeded inside pages, and display no error. All php package seems to be correctly installed.

Testing a simple: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, give a blank page

error log give:

[Fri Mar 02 20:30:13 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/lib/utils/setDocumentRoot.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Create a simple phpinfo(); file and reuqest it in your browser. Is this also just blank? If yes, check your apache logfiles for error messages.

Comment: Check the values of error_reporting / display_errors / log_errors / error_log in php.ini. Most likely they default to production values (i.e. show no errors). You might want to make those and other tweaks to suit your development environment.

Comment: Do a `php -v` on the command line - sometimes this will indicate a missing module or dependency that is preventing PHP from starting up. Edit: hmm, that said, your error makes it look like something is being run in addition to your normal PHP files. A php option that refers to setDocumentRoot.php maybe? Check your php.ini, htaccess and httpd.conf files.

Comment: Add an answer to your own question and mark it as read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve my problem, it was due to a fix i've set in my virtualHost config (who was calling a missing file: setDocumentRoot.php), i've disabled that script and all works great.